# Hide entire part of document using Sweave condition

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I would like to hide an entire part of my document including the LaTeX parts between code chunks.

The code might look like

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
if (showpart) {
@

Here we have quite a lot of latex, { that is not necessarily well-formed \end{itemize}

<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
}
@
```

I already tried to insert `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` using the verbatim package, but this does not cope well with the bad formed latex.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I believe this is really a LaTeX question rather than an Sweave question -- I would reformulate your in terms of the Swoven LaTeX file (i.e. don't include Sweave stuff to confuse regular latex users) and post to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: Yes and no. I already thought about that and came to the conclusion that including Sweave in the question could lead to different answers. I still hope there is a way to hide the code from latex, thus not even including it in the swoven file.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like `if (showpart) cat('\\begin{comment}')`, then `if (showpart) cat('\\end{comment}')`, with the option `results=tex`. The point is you have to output *valid* LaTeX code from R.

Comment: That is the idea I tried to mention below my code. However, \begin{comment} and \end{comment} do not work as expected once the code within is not well-formed.

Comment: I do not understand why you have to have ill-formed LaTeX code there. What are you going to do if `showpart` is `TRUE`?